# Library shows twice in site content

Tags: 2013, document-library, custom-list, bug

This question is for future reference, because I have already found the cause and it took me quite a bit of time.

I created a List definition with two list instances, A and B.

However when I look at the Site Contents I see 4 instances, 2 instances of list instance A en 2 list instances of B.

What I notices is that when I hover over the one the 3 dots appear on only 1 instance of 2 ( see picture). Also opening the library, both instances open the same library

Why is this happening 
 [image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I looked at my Schema.xml, I noticed that there were two default views defined.
Setting one of the views to False solved the problem.

```
<View BaseViewID="50" 
      DefaultView="TRUE" 
      MobileView="True"
      .....
</View>
```

Comment: that was something new..:)

Comment: this is one of those "what the F does one have to do with the other" quirks of sharepoint.